# App can't start on Android 2.3

Tags: java, android, logcat

My app doesn't want to start on Android 2.3 even though I made it for minimum 2.2, here is the LogCat. I tested in on both the emulator and on a device with 2.3 Android, it doesn't run at all, but on my other device with 4.0 it run's just fine... What could be wrong?

```
04-16 13:18:40.982: D/dalvikvm(6191): GC_CONCURRENT freed 41K, 49% free 2761K/5379K, external 3443K/4300K, paused 3ms+42ms
04-16 13:18:41.652: D/dalvikvm(6191): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 49% free 2761K/5379K, external 4643K/4643K, paused 2ms+10ms
04-16 13:18:41.942: D/AndroidRuntime(6191): Shutting down VM
04-16 13:18:41.942: W/dalvikvm(6191): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aac8578)
04-16 13:18:41.952: E/AndroidRuntime(6191): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 13:18:41.952: E/AndroidRuntime(6191): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {spec.sartheris.myapp/spec.sartheris.myapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 13:18:41.952: E/AndroidRuntime(6191):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2141)
04-16 13:18:41.952: E/AndroidRuntime(6191):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2156)
04-16 13:18:41.952: E/AndroidRuntime(6191):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1680)
04-16 13:18:41.952: E/AndroidRuntime(6191):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
04-16 13:18:41.952: E/AndroidRuntime(6191):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
04-16 13:18:41.952: E/AndroidRuntime(6191):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-16 13:18:41.952: E/AndroidRuntime(6191):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-16 13:18:41.952: E/AndroidRuntime(6191):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
04-16 13:18:41.952: E/AndroidRuntime(6191):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 13:18:41.952: E/AndroidRuntime(6191):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-16 13:18:41.952: E/AndroidRuntime(6191):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
04-16 13:18:41.952: E/AndroidRuntime(6191):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
04-16 13:18:41.952: E/AndroidRuntime(6191):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-16 13:18:41.952: E/AndroidRuntime(6191): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 13:18:41.952: E/AndroidRuntime(6191):     at spec.sartheris.myapp.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:47)
04-16 13:18:41.952: E/AndroidRuntime(6191):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1150)
04-16 13:18:41.952: E/AndroidRuntime(6191):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3832)
04-16 13:18:41.952: E/AndroidRuntime(6191):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2131)
04-16 13:18:41.952: E/AndroidRuntime(6191):     ... 12 more
04-16 13:18:42.002: D/dalvikvm(6191): GC_CONCURRENT freed 54K, 49% free 2775K/5379K, external 2543K/5243K, paused 2ms+13ms
```

here is the code in MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer music;
    int length;
    ImageView img;
    AnimationDrawable animation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        music = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.mymusic);
        music.setLooping(true);
        music.start();
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myanim);
        animation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getDrawable();
        animation.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        music.pause();
        length = music.getCurrentPosition();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        music.seekTo(length);
        music.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.about:
            Intent ia = new Intent("spec.sartheris.myapp.ABOUTUS");
            startActivity(ia);
            break;
        case R.id.exit:
            finish();
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: your error is here check line num 47 in MainActivity.java : spec.sartheris.myapp.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:47)

Comment: put you MainActivity code here...

Comment: you have a NullPointerException on line 47 in MainActivity.java. Kindly check that

Comment: It might be that the variable length is not initialized as well, since the android activity lifecycle is: onCreate() -> onStart() -> onResume(). You are using the length variable which in this case is null. In your code you should initialize length to 0 or similar.

Comment: nope, same thing, int length = 0, and nothing different happens

Comment: You also need to initialize music, as Mohamed_AbdAllah is telling you in his post. And you are doing it in your onWindowFocusChanged()

Comment: Did it, set the mediaplayer = null, and int = 0, everything loaded in the onCreate, and in onWindowFocusedChange only the 2 start methods, still getting error on 2.3 android

Answer (score 0):

`music` is not intialized.Initialize it in `onCreate()` as `onResume()` is run after `onCreate()`

Comment: how can I initialize it, there is no such method for mediaplayer

Comment: You already did initialize it in onWindowFocusChanged(). Therefore just move the code to onCreate().

Comment: @SartherisStormhammer You initialize a variable by calling its constructor or a method that returns an instance of the Class (like what you did in onWindowFocusChanged(): music = **MediaPlayer**.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.mymusic);

Comment: You must intialize the variable before using its methods (like what you did in onResume()

Comment: still nothing, initialized the MediPlayer even before the onCreate, in it, in the onResume, same, in the LogCat it says 
"Unable to to create media player"

Comment: for some reason .aac file wasn't playing on Gingerbread, that's why the error happened, replaced it with a normal .mp3 file and now works....

Answer (score 0):

Move this line under `onCreate()`:

```
music = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.mymusic);
```

Or you may add this in `onCreate()` instead:

```
MediaPlayer music = new MediaPlayer();
```

And then in `onWindowFocusChanged()` add your music file this way:

```
music.setDataSource("PathToFile");
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason .aac file wasn't playing on Gingerbread, that's why the error happened, replaced it with a normal .mp3 file and now works, weird...